# What is the correct usage of arrayWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is a bit basic; I am trying to retrieve http data for an iPhone app.

I have www.myhost.com/test.html that reads

```
<array><string>test</string><string>test2</string></array>
```

Then I have

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURLRLWithString:@"http://www.myhost.com/test.html"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:baseURL];
NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);
```

Which keeps returning (null). What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: You should start the habit of reading the API documentation for simple questions like this.

Comment: Try not to forget where you started from. 13k+ reputation or not. My question was completely valid within the SO FAQ guidelines. "Read the docs" has to be the most parroted response on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should probably be in a complete plist format (with doctype and all that)

[The man page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html)

easiest way to create a proper plist is with "Property List Editor.app"

on a side note: `NSLog(@"%@", [array description]);` is the same as `NSLog(@"%@", array);`

Answer (score 5):

The [arrayWithContentsOfURL documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfURL:) clearly states that

> The array representation at the
>   location identified by aURL must
>   contain only property list objects
>   (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or
>   NSDictionary objects).

That is, the kind of objects that you would obtain by calling the [writeToURL:atomically](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToURL:atomically:) method. The location written by this method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method `arrayWithContentsOfURL:` or the instance method `initWithContentsOfURL:`. Therefore, I suggest using these standard methods for writing and reading your arrays from an URL, instead of writing your own file and trying to read it by `arrayWithContentsOfURL:`.

Answer (score 0):

One additional discovery I made, is that if you are trying to build the list on the fly, to be served over the web rather than coming from a static file you create with the plist editor you must escape the strings.  If the document you has any xml errors in it your array will not load.  For example I had an & in some of my strings, and was still getting an empty array until I escaped the string and replaced & with `&amp;`